# Write program prints grade of all employees oracle error not select

Tags: oracle, plsql

h.  Write program prints grade of all employees

```sql
DECLARE
  v_lname VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  SELECT last_name INTO v_lname
  FROM employees
  WHERE first_name='John';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('John''s last name is :' ||v_lname);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' Your select statement retrieved 0 row.');
END;
```

how to `v_lname` repeat all data (`v_lname` only gets 1 while select out 3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much sense in what you posted.

Fixed, just to make it *look OK* (but still incorrect):

```
DECLARE
   v_grade  CHAR (1);       
BEGIN
   FOR loop_grade IN v_grade
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         SELECT job_id      
           INTO v_grade
           FROM employees
          WHERE job_id = 'AD_PRES';

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('A la :' || v_grade);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Your select statement retrieved 0 row.');
      END;
   END LOOP loop_grade;
END;
```

However, it won't work because e.g.

- you declared `V_GRADE` as a local variable which holds just one character, but - in `SELECT` statement - you're trying to put `AD_PRES` string into it. How come? Because `WHERE` clause suggests so
- `FOR` loop is wrong; you're using `LOOP_GRADE` which should be a cursor, but - you never declared it. Moreover, fetching it into the same `V_GRADE` variable most probably wouldn't work either
- if you want to catch an exception within the loop, you need to use an "inner" `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block`; if you used it at the "main" PL/SQL block, you'd catch only one exception and loop would stop processing. I can't tell, maybe that's what you wanted

Anyway: if you posted sample data and described what you want to do with it, someone would probably be able to assist.

---

Code you posted as a comment should be rewritten as:

```
DECLARE
   l_cnt  NUMBER := 0;                         -- count number of fetched rows
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT last_name
                   FROM employees
                  WHERE first_name = 'John')
   LOOP
      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('John''s last name is :' || cur_r.last_name);
   END LOOP;

   IF l_cnt = 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Your select statement retrieved 0 rows.');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

As you want to "loop" through all employees whose name is "John", use exactly that - a **loop**. It means that you don't have to worry about `NO_DATA_FOUND`; procedure would just silently finish. That's why you have to actually "count" number of fetched records in order to display a message if there's noone whose name is "John".

Comment: DECLARE
v_lname VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
SELECT last_name INTO v_lname
FROM employees
WHERE first_name='John';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('John''s last name is :' ||v_lname);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' Your select statement retrieved 0 row.');
END; how do v_lname add whole data (v_lname only gets 1 data while select out 3)

Comment: I fixed your code and posted it at the end of my answer. Have a look.